# Using PFQuery's containsAllObjectsInArray results in error

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery

I have the following code, where I attempt to retrieve users based on an array of user IDs:

```
NSArray *userIDsWhoLikedPhoto = [self.photo objectForKey:@"usersThatLikedPicture"];

PFQuery *userQuery = [PFUser query];
[userQuery whereKey:@"objectId" containsAllObjectsInArray:userIDsWhoLikedPhoto];
[queryQuery findObjectsInBackground];
```

However, I always get the error "`Error: $all only works on array fields (Code: 102, Version: 1.2.18)`". I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong, since I am passing in an array as the query term.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out:

```
[userQuery whereKey:@"objectId" containedIn:userIDsWhoLikedPhoto];
```